# Flutter logout to remove all routes

Tags: flutter

Below is my app widget tree. If user is not logged in then login page is shown if user is logged in then work page. on account page I have logout button.Logout button implements push replacement and shows login page.

Issue is - When user click on back button again work page is shown. 
How to remove all the routes from widget tree and only show login page after logout action?

Note - I am not using Named routes, just Push , Pop and Replacement

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close your dialog by calling,

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

and then call `pushReplacement`

```
void _doOpenPage() {
  navigator.pushReplacement(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MyHomePage()));
}
```

> `pushReplacement` Replace the current route of the navigator by pushing the given route and then disposing the previous route once the new route has finished animating in.

Read More [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushReplacement.html)

Comment: Logout is an alertDialogue, so push replacement close that dialogue and move to Login page but account page remains in the memory

Comment: did you called `Navigator.pop(context);` before `pushReplacement`

Comment: Pop and PushReplacement combination worked. you can edit  your answer to add your Navigator.pop(context); comment.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `namedRoutes`, you can do this by simply :

```
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, "/login", (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

Where `"/login"` is the route you want to push on the route stack.

Note That :

This statement removes all the routes in the stack and makes the pushed one the root.